# How to find heading substrings with org-mode internal links

Tags: org-mode, search

With point over the link here, `org-open-at-point` jumps to the following line ("ham eggs"):

```
* spam
** spam [[ham%20eggs][ham eggs]]
** ham eggs
```

Here however (final line extended), the same action makes emacs prompt `No match - create this as a new heading? (y or n)` in the minibuffer:

```
* spam
** spam [[ham%20eggs][ham eggs]]
** ham eggs spam
```

Is it possible to define links that do a substring search, so that the search would succeed in this case?  It certainly is possible when linking to non-org mode files, and I would like to do the same for internal links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `org-link-search-must-match-exact-headline` to nil.

```
(setq org-link-search-must-match-exact-headline nil)
```

Now this will search the buffer for 'ham eggs' (which does not need to
be in a heading.).

```
* spam [[ham eggs]]
* ham eggs spam
```

To restrict it to a heading (and an exact match), lead with a '*'.

```
* spam [[*ham eggs]]
* ham eggs spam
```

See `(info "(org)External links")` for more details.

Comment: After setting org-link-search-must-match-exact-headline, search works as you describe except that leading with a star does not limit to exact matches.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.  Leading with a star should work the way I described starting with version 8.3.  (A commit  from
December 2014, 6d691e2aa8e, introduced this change.)